# How do I pin versioned dependencies in Python when using both conda and pip?

Tags: python, conda, pip-tools

I'm trying to follow the best practice of installing fully pinned dependencies (for repeatable builds and better Docker caching, see [this pythonspeed.com article](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/pipenv-docker/)).

My project needs to use both conda and pip (conda for complex ML packages, pip for stuff not available on conda). The [conda-lock](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/conda-dependency-management/) and [pip-compile](https://hynek.me/articles/python-app-deps-2018/) tools are able to generate all transitive dependencies at pinned versions. However, these tools are **independent**: when I run pip-compile, it's not aware of the dependencies that conda-lock wants to install, and vice versa.

This results in different package versions, causing wasted space in the Docker image and potentially causing breakage/incompatibility, as the `pip install` step installs different versions of some transitive dependencies.

Does anyone have a better solution for creating pinned Python dependency lists when using **both conda and pip**?

(Edit: here's a github ticket on conda-lock to support pip dependencies: https://github.com/conda-incubator/conda-lock/issues/4)

Comment: what about using a requirement.txt with exact version of those packages you want to use, and you can use `pip install  =` to install the exact version

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a tool that solves the depedencies, you could just install all the dependencies and then use `conda env export` to generate a pinned/versioned `environment.yaml`.

Main downside: this is heavier weight, as it actually has to install all the dependencies. On the upside, you end up with just a single environment "spec" environment file as input, and a single environment "lock" file as output.

### Specify direct dependencies in environment-spec.yaml

Specify both conda and pip dependencies together. Example:

```yaml
name: base
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
  # etc.
dependencies:
  - matplotlib
  - pandas
  - pip  # needed to have a pip section below
  - scikit-learn
  - pip:
    - pyplot_themes  # only available on PyPI
```

### Install dependencies and export pinned versions (including transitive dependencies)

This could be done directly on your local machine, but here's how to isolate this process in Docker:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

# Note: using miniconda instead of micromamba because micromamba lacks the
# `conda env export` command.
FROM continuumio/miniconda3:4.9.2

COPY environment-spec.yml /environment-spec.yml
# mounts are for conda caching and pip caching
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/opt/conda/pkgs --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache \
    conda env create -n regen_env --file /environment-spec.yml

# Export dependencies.
RUN conda env export -n regen_env > /environment-lock-raw.yml
CMD ["cat", "/environment-lock.yml"]
```

Then you can create a pinned environment file like so (assuming the above dockerfile was named `regen_environment.Dockerfile`):

```sh
docker build -t regen_env -f regen_enviroment.Dockerfile .
docker run --rm regen_env > environment-lock.yaml
```

This outputs the pinned enviroment file to `environment-lock.yaml`, which you can then install with `conda install -f environment-lock.yaml`.

(Here's a gist with some more references and details: https://gist.github.com/jli/b2d2d62ad44b7fcb5101502c08dca1ae)

Comment: The downside of this approach is that you can't update just one package (without updating all your transitive dependencies). It looks like conda-lock plans to implement a pip integration in the near future, which could solve that issue, but it's not released yet.

Comment: Update: conda-lock has now released pip support. And, at least in my case, I found that a "lock" file generated using the suggested method here failed to solve a few months later with a new version of conda. Unfortunately it's hard to tell why this is because the conda solve failure output is next to useless, but for me it underscores the risks of having the solver involved even when you restore from the lockfile.